# EF Core Cosmos 3.1.3 extra calls

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights, ef-core-3.1

I have Asp.net core 3.1 a GetAll endpoint that returns a list of all items from the first Cosmos DB container. That service has an audit, that writes a record to the second Cosmos DB container in the same Database. GetAll endpoint makes two read requests to the first container. So endpoint makes only 3 requests to Cosmos DB (one write and two reads), but in the Azure Application Insights wrote that endpoint makes 7 requests. What that other 4 calls are? And is it possible not to do these requests and how? The connection to Cosmos DB is EF Core 3.1.3.

Application Insights's End-to-end transaction details

[image: Application Insights's End-to-end transaction details]

Comment: Can you show which are the actual addresses involved (you can hide the account name), that way we can understand what is happening, it's hard to know what they could be without any context. Are your Reads point reads or queries? Is this the first request you do to the account or are all requests having these extra calls?

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably seeing are the Query Plan Requests that are done by the SDK before each Cosmos DB request.

If you capture the web traffic with Fiddler, for example, you will see 2 web requests per action, the first one with this header:

```
x-ms-cosmos-is-query-plan-request: True
```

For further information refer to [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/4978).

Regards,
Andreas